# Weird optimization of C++ loop unrolling

Tags: visual-c++, assembly, x86-64, compiler-optimization

I'm implementing `template BigInt<size_t Chunks>` (integer of any compile-time fixed width) in C++ with loop unrolling.

Here are the parts of `bool operator <() const`'s assembly (VS 2010, /O2), when the operand is `BigInt` with higher number of `Chunks`.

When I compare lower (common) chunks, the code is exactly as expected:

```
mov         rax,qword ptr [rcx+18h]   //  get chunk of 'this'
mov         r8,qword ptr [rdx+18h]    //  get chunk of operand
cmp         rax,r8                    //  compare
jb          ADDRESS1                  //  jump below - "return true"
jne         ADDRESS2                  //  jump not equal - "return false"
...                                   //  next chunk
```

And I expected to see very similar code (except the second `mov`) when I compare higher chunks of operand with a sign-extension of 'this' operand:

```
mov         r8,qword ptr [rdx+18h]    //  get chunk of operand
cmp         rax,r8                    //  compare
jb          ADDRESS1                  //  jump below - "return true"
jne         ADDRESS2                  //  jump not equal - "return false"
...                                   //  next chunk
```

But I got this strange, inflated code:

```
mov         rax,qword ptr [rdx+40h]   //  get chunk of operand
cmp         rax,r8                    //  compare
sete        r9b                       //  save ZF (???)
cmp         rax,r8                    //  compare (identical, again!!!)
jb          ADDRESS1                  //  jump below - "return true"
test        r9b,r9b                   //  test saved ZF
je          ADDRESS2                  //  jump equal (ZF==0) - "return false"
...                                   //  next chunk
```

Does anyone have an idea, what happened here?

I'll add the original code upon request, but I think NO code should be left like this after optimization.